# Spring MVC cannot instantiate interface field inside form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on Spring MVC application and have form that has interface field inside.

```java
public class MyForm {
   private MyFieldInterface myField;
}
```

In the controller, in the request mapping method we have the form as model attribute

```java
@Controller
public class MyController
    @RequestMapping(value="/myAction")
    public String process(@ModelAttribute("myForm") MyForm form....
```

When it binds the request to the form it can not create the myField.
The error is
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [...MyFieldInterface]: Specified class is an interface

Data is comming from the JSP but myField is null.
It tries to create the field before putting the data from the request,
but it can not instantiate from Interface.

My question is - How can I force Spring to instantiate it from the class that implements this interface? Is this possible at all

```java
public MyClass implements MyFieldInterface
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. BeanInstantiationException is thrown because you cannot use a interface in a Spring form backing bean.
2. Do not use your own java classes in the form backing bean.
3. Use a java class that wraps a value of the primitive type in an object. Example : String, Long, Integer etc.